# Why does the Facebook dialog for Login Authentication disappear, without any error?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I know the question has been asked several times, but none of the solutions I have found has worked. I have tried the following:

1- Restart the phone
2- Check Internet connection
3- Set the application to be available to public in the Dashboard

None of these have worked. Below is the code snipet I have:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fbLogin);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
        // If using in a fragment
        loginButton.setFragment(this);

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Toast.makeText(about.this.getActivity(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(about.this.getActivity(),"Canceled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                Toast.makeText(about.this.getActivity(),"Failes with error: " +  exception,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Appreciate any advise and sorry for the repetitive question.

Comment: Is there any information in logcat which might help to shed some light on the problem?

Comment: there was no information in the log cat...

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue I update the following tag in the Manifest file

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

the app_id was previously set to the name instead of the numeric string app id.

example: facebook_app_id = 0000000000000000 not facebook_app_id = facebook_app_name